# Give me the code: ReversedString

Tags: python, string, loops

Assume that the variable `myString` refers to a string, and the variable `reversedString` refers to an empty string. Write a loop that adds the characters from `myString` to `reversedString` in reverse order.

I have no idea what this means, any help for a beginner? it is very much appreciated!

Thank you all who answered! It gives me hope for a beginner like myself that there are people who are willing to help someone else out! I in no way was asking for a straight answer just someone to help me understand the question. Which I understand now what they are asking!

Comment: Hint: how would you reverse a string? Write down a sentence on paper and reverse it.

Comment: string = 'my string' >>> for index in reversed(string): print (index) is this what he is asking for?

Answer (score 0):

It's asking you to write a loop.  The loop should look at each character of your string in reverse order.  If your string were `"abc"`, the loop should see `c`, then `b`, then `a`.  Inside the loop, you should put the character on the end of of the `reversedString` variable.

Comment: for _ in xrange(1): reversedString = myString[::-1]

Comment: @marcadian: That makes no sense.  Why are you using a loop for one iteration and ignoring the iterating variable?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain in simpler terms, this helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just do this

```
reversedString = ""
for c in reversed(myString):
    reversedString += c
```

The most pythonic way to do this tho is this:

```
myString = myString[::-1]
```

Comment: Thank you, I do recognize the 2nd one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stack:

```
>>>> s='String'
>>>> stack=list(s)
>>>> reversed=[]
>>>> while stack:
....    reversed.append(stack.pop())
.... 
>>>> reversed
['g', 'n', 'i', 'r', 't', 'S']
>>>> rstring=''.join(reversed)
>>>> rstring
'gnirtS'
```

You can use a 'for' loop with relative indexing:

```
>>>> rstring=''
>>>> for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
....    rstring+=s[-i]
.... 
>>>> rstring
'gnirtS'
```

Or, recursively:

```
>>>> def rrev(s):
....     if s == "":
....         return s
....     else:
....         return rrev(s[1:]) + s[0]
.... 
>>>> rrev('String')
'gnirtS'
```

Or, Pythonically:

```
>>>> s[::-1]
'gnirtS'
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: reverse string]
The image shows a string being reversed, using a for loop.

Comment: Post code as code and not as image. Bots will flag it for "Low quality answer". EoR.